# How to change type of elements in C++ boost multi array?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I receive a matrix with elements of type `unsigned char` from another function and I am trying to find its max value.

```
boost::multi_array<unsigned char, 2> matrix;
```

All elements are integers and so I was hoping to recast matrix as type `<int, 2>` then perform `std::max_element()` operation, but unsure how to recast type of a boost multi array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that to use `max_element`. `char` is an integral type just like `int`:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/39c93sMMa)**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    using boost::extents;
    boost::multi_array<unsigned char, 2> matrix(extents[10][5]);

    std::iota(         //
        matrix.data(), //
        matrix.data() + matrix.num_elements(), '\x30');

    fmt::print("matrix: {}\n", matrix);

    auto [a, b] = std::minmax_element(matrix.data(),
                                    matrix.data() + matrix.num_elements());

    // as integers
    fmt::print("min: {}, max {}\n", *a, *b);
    // as characters
    fmt::print("min: '{:c}', max '{:c}'\n", *a, *b);
}
```

Program stdout

```
matrix: {{48, 49, 50, 51, 52}, {53, 54, 55, 56, 57}, {58, 59, 60, 61, 62}, {63, 64, 65, 66, 67}, {68, 69, 70, 71, 72}, {73, 74, 75, 76, 77}, {78, 79, 80, 81, 82}, {83, 84, 85, 86, 87}, {88, 89, 90, 91, 92}, {93, 94, 95, 96, 97}}
min: 48, max 97
min: '0', max 'a'
```

### Reinterpreting View

If you must (for other reasons thatn using `max_element`) you **can** use a  `multi_array_ref`:

```
// reinterpreting view:
boost::multi_array_ref<const char, 2> view(
    reinterpret_cast<const char*>(matrix.data()),
    std::vector(matrix.shape(), matrix.shape() + 2));

fmt::print("view: {}\n", view);
```

Which prints [Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Pd4nzKEzv)

```
view: {{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4'}, {'5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}, {':', ';', '<', '=', '>'}, {'?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'}, {'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'}, {'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'}, {'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W'}, {'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\'}, {']', '^', '_', '`', 'a'}}
```

You can also reshape it:

```
view.reshape(std::vector{25, 2});
fmt::print("reshaped: {}\n", view);
```

Printing

```
reshaped: {{'0', '1'}, {'2', '3'}, {'4', '5'}, {'6', '7'}, {'8', '9'}, {':', ';'}, {'<', '='}, {'>', '?'}, {'@', 'A'}, {'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E'}, {'F', 'G'}, {'H', 'I'}, {'J', 'K'}, {'L', 'M'}, {'N', 'O'}, {'P', 'Q'}, {'R', 'S'}, {'T', 'U'}, {'V', 'W'}, {'X', 'Y'}, {'Z', '['}, {'\', ']'}, {'^', '_'}, {'`', 'a'}}
```

Comment: Added a literal answer to the question as asked just for good measure

Comment: And here's everything without using libfmt, just using iostream for output: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d36a83decb67d92b (pretty horrible, right :))